# your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM

Tags: algorithm, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I installed chrome on my machine. i am using `ubuntu 14.04` i can access website except google sites.. when tried to access google site i am getting this error,

[image]

how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing libnss3 fixed it for me on Ubuntu 14.04

## sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d

found this solution on https://nobopintu.wordpress.com/2017/06/10/ubuntu-google-chrome-your-connection-is-not-private-neterr_cert_weak_signature_algorithm-error/

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to create a plist file in XML format

```
cat >com.google.Chrome.plist <<POLICY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
POLICY
```

Convert it to binary format using plutil -convert binary1 com.google.Chrome.plist

Move it into your system preferences sudo cp com.google.Chrome.plist /Library/Preferences/

Now visit chrome://policy and ensure EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors is set to true and has OK status (requires Chrome restart)